# How to bypass authentication_user for only 1 method ? (using devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using devise and in my profile_controller.rb I have the usual 7 methods and an additional methods, now I am using before_filter as only authenticated user can access those methods but for just 1 method, I need it to bypass it. How to do it ?

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!

def index
   ...
end

...

def destroy
   ...
end

def edit_name
   ...
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: :method_you_want_to_bypass
```

In this way you skip the call to `authenticate_user!` method when the current action is `:method_you_want_to_bypass`. This solution works in general, not only with Devise.